# Power Automate: How can I copy a SharePoint list item with a multiple choice column to another list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, flow, power-automate, choice-field

I created a Power Automate flow that copies list items from one list to another. It works, except for...

There is one multiple choice column. It is called "Topic" and it has choices like "IT", "Finance", "General", "Other", "Country", "Business Line 1", "Business Line 2" etc. I would like to see the exact same choices in the new list too, there can be up to three or four choices. I made sure the same choices are predefined in the new list, too.

I got an example code, but it is not working. Instead of the topics, it writes `"[{"Value":"Finances"],[Value":"IT"},{"Value":"Other"}]"` (everything as one choice, instead of having the choices "Finances", "IT", "Other") in the new list.

This is the example code:

First part:

[image]

Second part (here, I changed the "Output from previous steps" to "Topics" instead of arrTopicValue, and it already improved the result a little bit)

[image]

This is how the array is in the end put into the item of the new list:

[image]

When I do all of this, the outcome in the end for the test item entry in the new list is: `[{"Value":"Finances"],[Value":"IT"},{"Value":"Other"}]`. Everything as one choice/line of text, instead of having the choices Finances, IT, Other.

I started taking a course on Udemy, but I am not sure I will be able to solve this problem afterwards.

---

I followed the description as in the thread linked in an answer below, however, in the last step my screen looks different and I can't put my variable arrTopics...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please follow the answer in this [thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Update-item-with-multiple-choice-columns/td-p/425901). I tested it again and works fine.

There is an mistake in the append to array variable 2 action.

You do not need to add a quotation mark around the value.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try and let you know if it works!

Comment: Hi!

I did everything like in the thread, however I can't manage to put the array variable in the end. And I can't see the sign marked in red in the thread either...

It looks like I can't put screenshots in here, I will add them to the question above!

Comment: @FranziskaD, please double check with your column settings, ensure you have enabled multi selection in that choice column.